# Is there a way for a package to know the extension (e.g. `.tex` or `.dtx`) of the real file processed?

Tags: package-writing, file-extensions

Is there a way for a (LaTeX) package to know whether the real file which is run by (say) `pdflatex` is `⟨file name⟩.tex` or `⟨file name⟩.dtx`?

Comment: The `currfile` package does, well, _not_ this. It uses the `.fls` file produced by the `-recorder` compiler flag to find out the name of the file being processed. However, in that package you need to specify the extension of the main file to guide the `.fls` parsing process. For your case you could maybe turn this around, you already know the base name (from `\jobname`, assuming that the `-jobname` flag is not used) and you can check if the first occurrence of that name in the `.fls` file is followed by `.tex` or `.dtx`.

Comment: Not sure if that would work properly/always, and if you are able to use the `-recorder` flag, potentially also multiple passes could be needed (the currfile manual mentions multiple passes for MikTeX only). If you can explain your use case a bit more then maybe more targeted solutions can be suggested.

Comment: @Marijn Thanks for the `currfile` reminder. I was hoping it could be used in a much simpler way than with `-recorder`/`.fls` but it seems to not be the case: if `mypackage.sty` contains `\RequirePackage{currfile}\ExplSyntaxOn\str_show:N \currfileext\ExplSyntaxOff` and my `.dtx` file contains (among other things) `\documentclass{ltxdoc}\usepackage{mypackage}`, the compilation displays `> \currfileext=tex.` (while there are no `.tex` file involved), so not `> \currfileext=dtx.`. I'm able to use the `-recorder` flag, but parsing the `.fls` would be overkilling for my (bit tricky) use case.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure but I think `\currfileext` only works for files that are opened _after_ `currfile` is loaded - so if you load `currfile` in the dtx before `\usepackage{mypackage}` then inside `mypackage` you can show the current extension.

Comment: @Marijn Unfortunately no. But it seems to be a limitation of the `currfile` to not be able to deal with `.dtx` extension: it has to be explicitly stipulated (see its `mainext` option). And that is precisely what I'd like to avoid: I'm looking for an automatic way of detecting a `.dtx` extension.

Comment: As I understand it `currfile` implements two separate approaches, one for files loaded after the package is activated (with `\input`, `\include`, `\usepackage` etc) and one for the main file, i.e., the file that contains `\usepackage{currfile}`. The approach for the subfiles can give you the extension, but the approach for the main file cannot and you have to specify it manually there.

Comment: @Marijn Too bad working with the main file is less handy than with subfiles...